# STATIC_ROOT и появление новых файлов во время работы сервера

Tags: django, nginx

Есть два пути: STATIC_ROOT на папку 'static' и STATICFILES_DIRS на папку 'static_files'. Nginx наблюдает за 'static' папкой. Перед запуском сервера делаем collectstatic и собираем все файлы в static (static перед этим должен быть пустым). Есть какая-то модель AModel с полем FileField, создающий файл в 'static_files'. Но при работе сервера, когда юзер добавит новый файл, то он будет создан в 'static_files', и, я думаю, nginx не сможет увидеть новый файл. Подскажите как быть с этим вопросом

Comment: Во время работы сайта никогда и ничего не должно создаваться в static. Для создаваемых на лету файлов существует специальный каталог media.

Comment: @andreymal понятно, спасибо! У меня media в static была, а это ошибка. Нужно вне папки static вынести.